# Как сверстать список товаров с эффектом наведения?

Tags: html, css, hover

Как сделать такую таблицу и чтобы при наведении был такой эффект?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Карточки - это <li>, с содержимым внутри. при наведении на <li> идет увеличение (transform) и наложение полупрозрачного background в li:after.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Выделяешь каждый продукт в div и даешь ему условное название (например, `item`).
Можно решить с помощью JavaScript или CSS:

1. Далее подключаешь javascript-код/jquery-код(как удобнее), который занимается тем, что отлавливает `hover` на элементе с классом/айдишником «item»:

   ```
   $( ".item" ).hover(
       тут идет твой код на изменения селекторов твоего div'а
   );
   ```

   Пример сделан на jQuery (прочитать подробнее можно [в официальной докудентации](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).
2. Можно использовать CSS и отслеживать `hover` через специальный псевдокласс:

   ```
   div.item:hover{
       /* тут стили, которые ты добавляешь для изменения формы, при наведении*/
   }
   ```

   Подробнее прочитать про hover можно на [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp).

Comment: не нужен тут никакой jQuery

Comment: можно и через css, просто привел пример через js/jquery, может он не только стили хочет менять

Comment: если можно через css, лучше делать через css.

Comment: желательно через css

Comment: сейчас дополню ответ тогда

Answer (score 1):

```css
.shop-item {
font-family:garamond;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
transition:1s all;
}
.shop-item-hover {
opacity:0;
visibility:hidden;
background:darkorange;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
transition:1s all;
}
.shop-item:hover .shop-item-hover {
opacity:0.5;
visibility:visible;
}

.shop-item:hover {
transform:scale(1.1);
box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<figure class="shop-item">
<img src="http://www.znakotveta.ru/i/Krovat-Florence-Art-Art-6301-00011153.jpeg" width="100">
<div class="shop-item-hover"></div>
<figcaption><h3>Кровати!</h3></figcaption>
</figure>
```